# Autodesk Forge Design automation - Revit IO: unable to upload application package to design automation app

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to explore design automation for Revit by exploring the code at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-revit.window.family.create. 
When I run the application, I get an error message

> "Failed to create the family:( "

and the following log -

> jstree.min.js:5 [Deprecation] document.registerElement is deprecated
>   and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use
>   window.customElements.define instead. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 for more
>   details. (anonymous) @ jstree.min.js:5 ForgeTree.js:348 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
>       at refreshTypeList (ForgeTree.js:348)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.spanRemove.onclick (ForgeTree.js:339)

Also while following the instruction in the provided code, most of the links give in README.md for Postman collection (https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/design-automation-for-revit/blob/master/Docs/AppBundle.md ) was in-accessible to me.

Comment: The links issue are fixed, sorry for that. Augusto answered the question as follow. actually, the main introduction and concept should be at the official Design Automation V3 API doc, and for Revit specific, https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/ is important to go through. Let me know any other specific question or what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you mentioned is on the browser side and it's related to the `jsTree`, which needs updating due to a browser change. We're fixing it on our samples.

About the overall error, it probably due to a missing setup on the sample. As a suggestion, I would suggest a basic tutorial for [Design Automation](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels). Back to the error, you probably need to check the `reports.txt` to see what happened during the **Workitem** execution.

We're also fixing a few broken links on the documentation, sorry about that. Are you looking for anything specific?

**Update**

Design Automation requires `code:all` scope.

Comment: Hi, Augusto, Zhong Wu
I downloaded the latest code and attempted to upload package using postman , Once Access token is obtained, I Faced Access issues when tried to use Get Engines API, Create App or any other API's. Can you check if you can reproduce the same issue.

Comment: @HrishikeshThakur what's the error message? Did you select Design Automation v3 when creating the app?

Comment: Yes I have created the app with DesignAutomation V3.
The error message obtained is " Token does not have the privilege for this request. "

Comment: I used following scopes : ' bucket:read bucket:update bucket:create bucket:delete data:write data:create data:read '

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I was able to make the API calls with scope code:all